# How to create a new custom field in Strapi that allows to upload document in S3 and storing the document's url

Tags: reactjs, field, custom-fields, strapi

Is it possible to create a custom field in Strapi that allows to select and upload document to AWS S3 and storing the document's url from S3 in that field.